# How to supply --prune-tags to git pull?

Tags: git

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/2.34.0:

> `-p` `--prune` Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following
> or due to a `--tags` option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for example if the remote was cloned with the `--mirror` option), then they are also subject to pruning. **Supplying `--prune-tags` is a shorthand for providing the tag refspec.**

However, my git pull gives me an error:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.34.1.windows.1

$ git pull --prune-tags
error: unknown option `prune-tags'

$ git pull --prune --prune-tags
error: unknown option `prune-tags'

$ git pull --prune --tags --prune-tags
error: unknown option `prune-tags'
```

Even:

```
$ git pull --prune --tags origin --prune-tags
error: unknown option `prune-tags'
```

However, this works, assuming `t1` is a name of the tag:

```
$ git pull --prune --tags origin t1
From ssh://[stripped]
 * tag               t1         -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it looks like a bug in how options are handled by `git pull`.

Testing with `git version 2.35.0` :

- `git pull --prune --prune-tags origin` yields "unknown option 'prune-tags'"
- but `git fetch --prune --prune-tags origin` works (and deletes said tags)

---

[update]

as @torek commented, note that the option is not listed in `git pull` options : `--prune-tags` is hinted at in the `--prune` section of `git help pull`, which is the same paragraph as the one from `git help fetch`. It would however make sense for `git pull` to handle that option as well.

Comment: It's kind of a documentation bug, and kind of a `git pull` bug: `--prune-tags` or `-P` is a `git fetch` option but not a `git pull` option. So pull fails to pass it through to fetch as an option. The documentation is built from pieces, and the `-p` description (for the regular `--prune` option) has a reference to the `--prune-tags` option. It seems to me that pull should support it and pass it through (or, now that pull is C code, support it and set the variable ) and then the doc glitch can be fixed by just documenting both options for both commands.

Comment: @torek: you are right, updated the answer accordingly

Comment: From what I understood form the docs, `--prune-tags` is a "refspec", so that i can use it as in my last example: `git pull --prune --tags origin --prune-tags`. It is not a `git pull` option.

Comment: @PiotrKubiak it is a shortcut to inject a refspec. Your comment made me realize the following point : you can also type that refspec explicitly: `git pull --prune origin "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*" master` (add a `+` if you want to force update all your existing local tags that could have been updated on the remote)